# Perl command executing good when run on command line but not working in the Perl script

Tags: perl

Below is the code I'm trying to execute. I have mentioned the line 266 in the code. I have added that code to remove the blank lines in the log file. I'm not sure whether we can run the `perl` command inside a Perl script. Is there another way that I can run this so that I can remove the blank lines in the log file?

Below is the error I'm getting while running through the Perl script:

```
syntax error at ./reportJBossErrors.pl line 266, near "n -e "
Execution of ./reportJBossErrors.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Here is a portion of the code, showing line 266:

```
sub main {
    readConfiguration($config_file);
    $short_hostname = `hostname | cut -f 1 -d.`;
    chomp $short_hostname;
    getFileandInstance($short_hostname);
    $yesterday = getYesterday();
    validateEnvironment();
    $log_file = getLogFile($FMASK,$yesterday);
    perl -i -n -e "print if /\S/" $log_file; # 266 line. This is where I'm getting the compilation error
    processFile($log_file);
    $html_out = writeEmail();
    sendEmail($CONFIG{"FROMADDR"},$CONFIG{"TOADDR"},"Normal",
    "JBOSS",$short_hostname,$log_file,$CONFIG{ENVTYPE},$html_out);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can not call the `perl` command inside a Perl program as if it were a Perl builtin function.  You can use [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system) to run an external command:

```
my $cmd = 'perl -i -n -e "print if /\S/"';
system "$cmd $log_file";
```

You need to be careful of quoting.  Since you have a file name/path in the Perl variable `$logfile`, which you want to interpolate, that can go inside double quotes.  Since you do not want to interpolate `\S`, that should go in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot invoke the `perl` executable inside a Perl program as if it were a Perl builtin function. Instead, use the **list** form of [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) to run an external command. Don't forget to check if the command succeeded:

```perl
my @cmd = (perl => '-i', '-n', '-e', 'print if /\S/', $log_file);

system(@cmd) == 0
    or die "system @cmd failed: $?";
```

In general, I would recommend using the full path to `perl` rather than relying on `$PATH`.

Also, if you need to keep track of status etc, use [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny) to get both `STDOUT` and `STDERR` of the command you are running so that you can log error information.

Comment: When i'm executing the script it's getting the below error. The file is there in the correct directory.
Can't open server_pdbsdms1_bts1.log.2021-11-02: No such file or directory

Comment: You need to either 1) ensure that the working directory of the script is the directory in which the file is located; or 2) set `$log_file` to the full path to the target file.

Comment: The file is in different path. I went with the second option but still throwing the same error. I tried hardcoding the file with full path but still it's getting the same error.